# Listing latest actions using opengraph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

We're developing an application, based on the open graph API. In our application the user will read news and after 15 seconds of reading an action will appear on the reader's wall.

I need a way, using the open graph API, to get the last actions, posted on the reader's wall. I need it in order to give the users the ability to delete those actions. I found in the facebook documentation how to delete an action, using the action's `id`.

However I could not find how to get the latest actions `ids` that came from my App.

Is there a way to get them or I must store them on my server after a successful action post?

P.S I am using the javascript API.

Answer (score 1):

Just issue a GET request to the API asking for `/userid/app_namespace:action_name`, and it will return the actions of that type published for that user.

Comment: I'm using the default action types, so it might be different. The code above does not work. `/USER_ID/news.reads` works fine with the default action types, but it gives me all the news from all my applications. Any ideas how to filter them without looping through the array?